# Grails json converter with multiple deep levels

Tags: json, grails, groovy, marshalling

I'm having problems getting all the associated objects from a Groovy db mo into a final json render. 
I have the following code for a Report class:

```
static marshalling = {
    json {
        slides {
            shouldOutputIdentifier true
            shouldOutputVersion false
            shouldOutputClass false
            deep 'slides'
         }
    }
}
```

I need to send the object through a json api. I noticed that the conversion was shallow so I added `deep 'slides'` to get those objects in the final json instead of only ids.

This is how it gets rendered:

```
JSON.use('slides') {
   render report as JSON
}
```

Which works as expected. My problem is that inside each slide there's another associated array object called slideTiles and it's currently just showing ids.

Is there a way to keep going "deep" in the marshaling? I could also go another route, my main goal is to get a complete json object to send as a response.